# Exporting a module object and importing specific properties of said module

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a JS Module, in which I want to export an object concerning functions declared in the same file.
Ideally, I would like to import only the properties of the exported object, instead of importing the whole object and deconstructing it. Is it possible in some manner?

module.js

```
export const foo = {
   bar: () => console.log("foobar")
}
```

component.js

```
import { bar } from './module.js'

bar();
```

The current problem is that the bar isn't recognized as a function.

Comment: Hi, did you try ```ìmport { foo } from './module.js'``` and 
```foo.bar();``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm writing a JS Module, in which I want to export an object with reference to functions declared on the same file.

There's no reason to have that object. That's what modules are for. The bindings you export become part of a module object (you never get a direct reference to it), so there's no need for you to explicitly create the object — and doing so gets in a the way a bit, and prevents *tree-shaking* (eliminating code that is never used).

> Ideally, I would like to import only properties of the exported object, instead of importing the whole object and deconstructing it.

With your current approach, that's what you have to do, e.g.:

```
import { foo } from "./module.js";
```

then to use `bar`, either use `foo.bar();` or destructure:

```
const { bar } = foo;
bar();
```

That's because what you've exported isn't `bar`, it's `foo`, an object that has a property called `bar`. Your `import` should be failing, because there's no named export called `foo`. (But if you're using a bundler, it may be obscuring that error.)

But again, there's no need for that object. Instead, just do this:

`module.js`:

```
export function bar() {
    console.log("foobar");
}
```

or

```
export const bar = () => {
    console.log("foobar");
};
```

Then your `import` in `component.js` will work.

Comment: Yeah, this works perfectly for me. I was just trying to figure out if importing the property directly was possible without destructuring.
Thanks for the quick and correct answer!